# pass in content of css into directive

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

Is there a way to use the content of css for a directive.  I want to reuse a directive and then in that directive, set the class so that way the content can be different icons from FontAwesome?

template

```
 <div class="modal-tooltip" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="CSS-CLASS-I-WANT-TO-PASS-IN"></span>
        <div class="tooltip-body">
            <span ng-transclude></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

directive

```
restrict = "E";
        scope = {
            alignment: "@"
        };

        template = Templates.toolTip;
        transclude = true;
        controller = ["$scope", ($scope) => {

        }];
```

.MY-CSS-CLASS-I-WANT-TO-CHANGE-THE-CONTENT-OF

```
content: "\f059";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the FontAwesome class to your custom directive to apply to the template.

In my example, the FontAwesome class is set using the `icon` attribute.

```
 <custom-button icon="fa fa-facebook"> Facebook</custom-button>
```

And in my directive, I take this value and apply the class to my `<span>` tag.

```
app.directive('customButton', function() {
        return {
           restrict: 'E',
           transclude: true,
           scope: {
              icon: '@'
           },
           template: "<button>" +
                        "<span class={{icon}}>" +
                        "</span>" + 
                        "<strong ng-transclude>" +
                        "</strong>" +
                     "</button>"
           } 
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle with my example in action: https://jsfiddle.net/cpgoette/ufgys7j0/